# Output backspace character in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, console, terminal, backspace

How can I move my backspace character to the beginning of string in console?
I tried to use `/r` and `/b` but it doesn't work.

P.S. I'm using Mac OS X. Sorry, but I hadn't found anything that could help me.

Comment: Are you using bash/Terminal? Do you have any code?

Comment: I need to use it printing thru my Python-application. I want to overwrite printed string.

Answer (score 0):

please use next keys combination:

```
CTRl+a
```